# Get HTML from Outlook's message editor - ControlType.Document

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am trying to fetch HTML from the Outlook. Text format is set to HTML and that is what will be received by the exchange server after I send it.

I am able to get text using:

```
if (e.Current.ControlType == ControlType.Document && e.Current.Name == subject+" - Message")
{
       TextPattern v = (TextPattern)e.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern);
       System.Console.WriteLine("DOC:"+ v.DocumentRange.GetText(-1));
}
```

Is there any way to read HTML from the editor using .NET automation features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're working with the wrong class. I extracted the following snippet from an example on the Microsoft support website. HTMLBody is a getter/setter (although it is used as a setter in this example).

```
Outlook.MailItemClass mItem = (Outlook.MailItemClass)doc.MailEnvelope.Item;
mItem.Subject = strSubject;
mItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
mItem.HTMLBody = GetString(strBody);
```

[The full article is available here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819398#bookmark-3)

Comment: I am working with ui automation `System.Windows.Automation`. Message was created by something else (website) and I just have to save HTML and click the send button.  You are, on another hand, showing `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` functionalities.  I did not consider it yet, since I was hoping to get it done just with ui automation.  With the Iterop it would probably involve saving to drafts, I am not sure yet... More to be done. Thanks for a hint. I will check it out. Probably this is the only way to go with. Thank you.